# Prisma auto generates migration even if there are no changes to schema

Tags: postgresql, migration, prisma

I have a simple Prisma schema (I'm only using the relevant part):

```
enum ApprovalStatus {
  APPROVED
  DENIED
  PENDING
}

model Attendee {
  user  User  @relation(fields: [user_id], references: [id])
  user_id BigInt
  event Event @relation(fields: [event_id], references: [id])
  event_id  BigInt
  status  ApprovalStatus @default(APPROVED)
  created_at  DateTime  @default(now())
  updated_at  DateTime?  @updatedAt
  deleted_at  DateTime?

  @@id([user_id, event_id])
  @@unique([user_id, event_id])
  @@map("attendees")
}
```

After saving the schema I run `npx prisma migrate dev`, and it creates the migration and successfully migrates. A quick peek in postgres shows that the table is created and a `\dT+` shows that the new type and the 3 entries, have been added as well.

Then I noticed that subsequent runs of migration started adding some weird alter table lines for the attendees table, for no reason. I checked the migration and there was no reason for it. Here's the migration of the attendee table, and as you can see status column is quite clearly defined:

```
-- CreateTable
CREATE TABLE "attendees" (
    "user_id" BIGINT NOT NULL,
    "event_id" BIGINT NOT NULL,
    "status" "ApprovalStatus" NOT NULL DEFAULT 'APPROVED',
    "created_at" TIMESTAMP(3) NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    "updated_at" TIMESTAMP(3),
    "deleted_at" TIMESTAMP(3),

    CONSTRAINT "attendees_pkey" PRIMARY KEY ("user_id","event_id")
);
```

And now, even if there were no changes to anything in the schema, and all previous migrations were properly applied, running `npx prisma migrate dev` (with or without --create-only) will always generate a migration with following:

```
/*
  Warnings:

  - The `status` column on the `attendees` table would be dropped and recreated. This will lead to data loss if there is data in the column.

*/
-- AlterTable
ALTER TABLE "attendees" DROP COLUMN "status",
ADD COLUMN     "status" "ApprovalStatus" NOT NULL DEFAULT 'APPROVED';
```

It's acting as if the type or name of the column has changed, even though there were no changes to the model or even entire schema for that matter. If I run the generate command more times, it will create this same migration each time with the exact same content. I thought it might have something to do with migration order, but unless it's doing migrations randomly, ApprovalStatus migration comes before attendees does. I really see no reason for it to behave this way, but I'm uncertain how to proceed. Any advice would be welcome.

EDIT: Additional info

"prisma": "^4.6.0"

"express": "^4.17.2"

"typescript": "^4.8.4"

psql (15.0, server 12.13 (Debian 12.13-1.pgdg110+1))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There was a regression introduced in Prisma v4.6.0 where Prisma drops and recreates an enum field as can be seen in this [issue](https://github.com/prisma/prisma/issues/16180). This was fixed in Prisma [v4.6.1](https://github.com/prisma/prisma/releases/tag/4.6.1). Kindly update to the latest version and you should not experience this issue with Prisma migrate.